# Index Match, Drag Down Index Command to get data from columns?

Tags: excel

I have index match formual that gets data from another sheet, the problem with the data is that the source columns change to +10 offsit each time, how can I auto fill the rows for almost 100 rows of data.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TrainExp!C:C,MATCH($D$2,TrainExp!$A:$A,0)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(TrainExp!M:M,MATCH($D$2,TrainExp!$A:$A,0)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(TrainExp!W:W,MATCH($D$2,TrainExp!$A:$A,0)),"")
```

please note that the next row should have data like this

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TrainExp!AG:AG,MATCH($D$2,TrainExp!$A:$A,0)),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `TrainExp!C:C` with `OFFSET(TrainExp!C:C,0,ROWS($1:1)*10-10`
It will refer to every 10th column with ending 3 (3,13,23...) and just fill down.

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` is probably best:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("TrainExp!C"&ROW(A1)*10-7,FALSE),MATCH($D$2,TrainExp!$A:$A,0)),"")`

Just be careful with deleting rows or column A.